# Parallel ForEach

Tags: multithreading, powershell, powershell-4.0, parallel.foreach

I've been trying to find a way to make the code below work in parallel, I tried jobs but the threads didn't return any data. one of those CSV files has over 100k records and the other has 20k. the `Where-Object` is taking about 5 seconds or so to finish, at that rate it would take me over a week to get all the bad assets located.

```
$AssetsDB = Import-Csv .\DBExport.csv
$RecordedAssets = Import-Csv .\RecordedAssets.csv

foreach ($Record in $RecordedAssets) {
    $AssetsMatch = $AssetsDB | Where {$_.Serial -eq $Record.Serial}

    if ($Record.Location -ne $AssetsMatch.Location) {
        Write-Output "$($AssetsMatch.Serial),$($AssetsMatch.Location),$($Record.Location)"
    }
}
```

After going at it for a couple hours I have realized it's above my head so now I need some help

EDIT:

Here's my original attempt at running jobs

```
$job = {
    foreach ($Record in $RecordedAssets) {
        $AssetsMatch = $AssetsDB | Where {$_.Serial -eq $Record.Serial}
        if ($Record.Location -ne $AssetsMatch.Location) {
            Write-Output "$($RecordMatch.Serial),$($RecordMatch.Location),$($Record.Location)" 
        }
    }
}
$threads = (1..20)

foreach ($t in $threads) {
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $job
}
Get-Job | Wait-Job
$JobOutput = Get-Job | Receive-Job
```

Comment: Without testing and looking real quickly, would using a Workflow and Foeach parallel work?    Workflow Compare-Files
{
    $AssetsDB = Import-Csv .\DBExport.csv
    $RecordedAssets = import-csv .\RecordedAssets.csv

foreach -parallel ($Record in $RecordedAssets)
{
    $AssetsMatch = $AssetsDB | Where {$_.Serial -eq $Record.Serial}

    if ($Record.Location -ne $AssetsMatch.Location)
    {
      Write-Output "$($RecordMatch.Serial),$($RecordMatch.Location),$($Record.Location)"
    }

}
}

Comment: Jobs or runspaces are the way to go here(imo workflows add a bunch of needless complications to a simple process like this).  Can you show the code you used to attempt this with PSJobs?  It's likely I can help you get it working.

Comment: you can receive the job using Receive-Job with job name. And that will give you the job output

Comment: @PetSerAl, correct me if i'm wrong here, but it's that hash table dropping the location property from the record?

Comment: @JonnyBoy, I tried running your code, but after calling the workflow nothing occurs.

Comment: @MikeGaruccio, I added my attempt at using jobs on the original post

Comment: @LPG Hash table do not affect object in any way. It just store object (`$_`) by key (`$_.Serial`) for fast lookup.

Comment: You use `$RecordMatch` in your code, but you never define it anywhere. Also, starting the same loop 20 times in parallel isn't going to speed up anything. On the contrary. Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you want to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you need the code to do exactly?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, I fixed $RecordMatch. I changed some internal variable names uique to our company and fat fingered that one.

My end goal is to run multiple threads for the lookup that match the serials and output their properties.

I was able to greatly speed up the process by using the has table that PetSerAl mentioned, however i'm still interested in finding out a way to get multithreading to work.

Comment: Since you already switched to hashtable lookups I wouldn't expect multithreading to notably speed things up further. Reading the input files is more likely to be your biggest bottleneck now.